# Align textbox at the center

Tags: html

I have this `textbox`

```
<form action="/index.php" method="post">
    <input style="width: 450px;" name="url" type="text" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to align it at the center. How can I do this?

Comment: do you want align the textbox text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the form inside a div. Style the div to align its child to center as:

```
<div style="text-align:center" >
   <form action="/index.php" method="post">
   <input style="width: 450px;" name="url" type="text" /> <input type="submit"      value="Submit" /></form>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.